# How to drag and drop same element multiple times into another div box in JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have two HTML div boxes. Let's say box A and box B. I want to drag and drop box A multiple times into box B. If I drop box A outside of box B then box A will revert back to it's original position. After I dropped the box A (clone) into box B I want to move box A (clone) into any position in box B. For now I did the codes to do that.

Now what I want is after I dropped box A into Box B, then if I drag and drop box A (clone) outside of box B, then box A (clone) need to hide or revert into it's original position (box A parent position).

HTML Codes

```
<div id="boxB"></div>
    
        <br>

<div class="boxA">BOX A</div>
```

CSS Codes

```
#boxB {
    width: 200px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    padding: 50px 50px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.boxA {
    width: 40px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #F5D938;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript + jQuery Codes

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
var x;

        $(".boxA").draggable(
        {
            helper: "clone",
            cursor: "move",
            revert: true
        });

        $("#boxB").droppable(
        {
            accept: ".boxA",
            drop: function(event, ui) 
            {
              x = ui.helper.clone();
              ui.helper.remove();
              x.appendTo('#boxB');
              $(x).draggable();
            }
        });
    });
```

You can see demo : https://jsfiddle.net/zajjith/3kedjgb0/10/

If I drag and drop box A (clone) outside from box B then that clone box A need to revert back to it's original parent box A position or hide or delete.

I hope you understand what I want. Please check my codes and help me.

Comment: To confirm, you want to revert the dragged item if it is lands outside of the Drop target.

Comment: May you explain me? or can you add the codes in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Example at https://jqueryui.com/droppable/#revert

Using your code, you can do the following.

```js
$(function() {
  function getBounds(el) {
    var p = $(el).position();
    p.right = p.left + $(el).width();
    p.bottom = p.top + $(el).height();
    return p;
  }

  function isOver(a, b) {
    var ap;
    if (typeof a == "object") {
      ap = a;
    } else {
      ap = getBounds(a);
    }
    var bp = getBounds(b);
    return (ap.left > bp.left && ap.right < bp.right) && (ap.top > bp.top && ap.bottom < bp.bottom);
  }
  $(".boxA").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#boxB").droppable({
    accept: ".boxA",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var cl = ui.helper.clone();
      cl.appendTo(this).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        stop: function(e, ui) {
          if (isOver($.extend({}, ui.position, {
              right: ui.position.left + ui.helper.width(),
              bottom: ui.position.top + ui.helper.height()
            }), $("#boxB")) == false) {
            var a = getBounds($("body > .boxA"));
            ui.helper.animate({
              top: a.top,
              left: a.left
            }, function() {
              ui.helper.remove();
            });
          } else {
            console.log("Drop Inside");
          }
        }
      });
      ui.helper.remove();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#boxB {
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.boxA {
  width: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F5D938;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="boxB"></div>
<br />
<div class="boxA">BOX A</div>
```

Comment: I already did this part. Now I want is after I drag and drop BOX A into BOX B, then If I drag and drop box A (clone) outside from box B then that clone box A need to revert back to it's original parent box A position or hide or delete. I hope you understand

Comment: Please check this : https://jsfiddle.net/zajjith/3kedjgb0/10/

Comment: Thank you very much Twisty. You are a life saver. And I want to know is there any way to revert the clone Box A to the original parent Box A position?

Comment: @ZajjithVedha oh I see, so if the user drops it from outside to inside, it sticks, but it they drop that same item from inside to outside, it reverts back to primary position and goes "away", like being deleted.

Comment: @ZajjithVedha I have updated it with a very lite edge detection system.

Comment: Thank you very much Twisty. You are a genius.

Comment: Hey, what should I need to do if I add two Box A boxes. Please see this demo. https://jsfiddle.net/zajjith/3kedjgb0/19/

Comment: @ZajjithVedha I wold suggest using a more unique class. Maybe `box a` and `box c`.